# Prevent IOS to relaunch an app when I switch app to Facebook in safari

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am really stuck on this problem and I need your help! I'm doing an iPhone  app.When iPhone swap between app and Facebook redirection in safari , iPhone shutdown the app for memory saving.
What I am doing is I am providing fb sharing in background from my app.
When I am doing fb sharing its shares successfully in background and comes back to my app successfully.At that time my app is not crashing. But when I go to safari and type Facebook and open fb site to check my shared post , in background my app is crashing.
This issue is coming in iPhone with iOS 7, I am not facing this issue in iOS 8.Check this post : [Prevent IOS to shutdown an app when it app switch to facebook for login and permission request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992819/prevent-ios-to-shutdown-an-app-when-it-app-switch-to-facebook-for-login-and-perm) but this solution doesn't work for me as I am using pod to install fb and doing background share.

Comment: You have obviously a bug in your code that crashes the app. This has nothing to do with Facebook. Get the crash log and debug it

Answer (score 0):

Though it's too late to answer this but I believe it may be helpful for others.

In [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) under *"Being a Responsible Background App"* section it was said that
your background running app would be terminated if it doesn't follow one of the given requirements.

You can familiarize with the full documentation. I'll quote 2 of them which exactly fit your problem:

> ### **Being a Responsible Background App**
>
> The foreground app always has precedence over background apps when it comes to the use of
>   system
>   resources and hardware. Apps running in the background need to be
>   prepared for this discrepancy and adjust their behavior when running
>   in the background. Specifically, apps moving to the background should
>   follow these guidelines:
>
> - **Do not make any OpenGL ES calls from your code.** You must not create an EAGLContext object or issue any OpenGL ES drawing commands
>     of any kind while running in the background. Using these calls causes 
>     your app to be killed immediately. Apps must also ensure that any
>     previously submitted commands have completed before moving to the
>     background. For information about how to handle OpenGL ES when moving 
>     to and from the background, see Implementing a Multitasking-aware
>     OpenGL ES Application in OpenGL ES Programming Guide.
> - **Do minimal work while running in the background.** The execution time given to background apps is more constrained than the amount of
>     time given to the foreground app. Apps that spend too much time
>     executing in the background can be throttled back by the system or
>     terminated.

To sum up, maybe your app is doing one of the above-given tasks when it's moved to the background after Facebook sharing.